# How to calculate the angle of the direction from two GPS coordinates

Tags: java, gps, coordinates

i have found a great way to calculate the angle of the direction from two coordinates, and i have tried the solution in excel, it worked fine when i typed the approximately coordinates. But if i implement the code in java, i got complately different results at dxy (angle) double variables. The coordinates are fine, i double checked them. :)

```
    double lon1 = (double)Math.round(LongitudeDouble * 1000000) / 1000000;
    double lat1 = (double)Math.round(LatitudeDouble * 1000000) / 1000000;

    double lon2 = 19.055954;
    double lat2 = 47.569331;

    ***************************

    double dy = (lat2 - lat1);
    double dx = Math.cos(Math.PI/180*lat1)*(lon2-lon1);

    double dxy = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    double degree = 180/Math.PI*dxy;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the degree of the direction"? Are you talking about an angle in spherical coordinates?

Comment: yes, im talking about the angle.

Comment: I can only recommend to use the debugger in Eclipse and check if each value is calculated as expected. Slight differences between Excel and Java calculation are normal but really big ones shouldn't happen.

Comment: I have already printed every each result in a textview to check what is wrong exactly, and the results of dx, dy is just fine. The dxy returns with something else and the degree furthermore complately wrong. Probably Math.atan2 in java is not equal with the atan2 in excel.

the first two coordinate is the following;
  double lon1 = 19.053143;
  double lat1 = 47.570518;

According to this, the result degree should be something around 90 degree, but in java the result is -17.

Comment: So dlon is about 0.003 degrees and dlat ~0.001 degrees. +-17 sounds reasonable. 90 degrees would be wrong.

Comment: the way i use the degree is probably misleading. In this case, the -17° means that the java says the second GPS coordinate if at north-west a little bit from the first GPS coordinate. But actually, its at western direction, around 90°. That is the problem.

Comment: i have read in wiki about atan2() that in some spreadsheets they used reversed arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why excell deviates from your program code, is that excell uses argument order: x,y while programming languages like java  use order (y,x). see the docu for [atan2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29).

Further, you and some other posts in SO
 confuse mathematical angles (east = 0 counterclockwise raising) and geografical directions in degrees (compass rose) : north = 0, clockwise). after the angle calculation which delivers mathematical angles, you must transform to geo directions, but:

you use the wrong formula. Your formula works for cartesian coordinates (e.g screen points, pixels), not for spherical (lat, long). search here on SO for **bearing between two coordinates**

`atan2` delivers an value from [-pi, pi]. but geo direction is 0-360.

by the way the correct answer:

Bearing/heading/course from lat1,lon1 to lat,lon2 =  `122.0402`

So the formula is partly nonsense:
Your code gives -32.04
1. So you first exchanged *from-point* and *to-point*; an angle is measured from p1 to p2.
2. -90 -32 = -122 which is the expected result. (mathematical vs. geo angles)

So you are messing up your own numbers. you typed in Excell another number than in java,
or posted the wrong number: the result in your java  code is -32.04
Using these numbers:

```
double lon1 = 19.053143;
double lat1 = 47.570518;

double lon2 = 19.055954;
double lat2 = 47.569331;
```

Comment: thanks for the information but still this can't be the whole problem. swapping x and y might transform 17° into 90°-17° or so. the change from math to geo direction adds a multiple of 90° and a minus sign. the cartesian calculus makes a minor difference since his sample points are quite close to each other. So this can't explain the discrepancy between 17° and his excel value of 90°

Comment: If you want you can find out why your wrong formula deviates by implementing it in excell with many intermediate steps, and check line per line where it starts deviating.

Comment: Updated with detailed analysis.

Comment: -32.04=147.96-180. reckon something? as you said one error is math vs geo 0°-definition and another is from-point vs to-point. this kind of detail is what the question **keeps** failing to provide, therefore -1. now You punish me for deficiencies in the formula but I just tried to prove him wrong with **his** own formula. is 122 anywhere near 90? no. because there's yet another error in his calculation and he's too lazy to figure it out and excel is not suitable for being posted here. the reason I write this here is that I'm off. I deleted my answer.